# How to pull specifics from tumblr posts when searching tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, response, tumblr

How do I pull specifics from tumblr posts when searching tags?
For example, my code looks like this:

```
tagpost = client.tagged("lol", :limit => 1)

tagpost["tagged"].each do |posts|
    puts posts["id"]
end
```

The error reads

`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from tumblr.rb:67:in <main>'`

I'm trying to just get the posts ids to show after searching with tags.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: why not just raise `tagpost.inspect`, see the content and then iterate with right approach?

Comment: I guess it should be `tagpost.each` instead of `tagpost["tagged"].each`.

Comment: @mudasobwa you're right :)

Comment: for future debugging, use `p post["id"]` instead of `puts` (the first will call `.inspect` and the latter `.to_s`

Comment: @audreydeineko I tried .inspect and it gave me the same result as posting  without any specific methods called

Comment: @MusannifZahir ok, wow...learn something new everyday